# Creating a table based on user inputted rows and columns in .xhtml

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//w3c//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

 <html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
    <title> Mrudul Patel </title>   
    <script>
        function myFunction() //function to create table based on user inputted rows and columns
        {
            var rows = prompt("Please enter number of rows", ""); //create prompt for rows
            var columns = prompt("Please enter number of columns",""); //create prompt for columns
            var table = document.createElement('table');
            var table2 = document.getElementById('taskname').value;

            for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++)
            {
                rows = table.insertRow(-1);
                for (car c = 0; c < columns; c++)
                {
                    columns = rows.insertCell(-1);
                    columns.appendChild(document.createTextNode(taskName));
                }
            }
            document.getElementById('holdTable').appendChild(table);
        };
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <p>Click "Try it" button for prompt for rows and column</p>
    <button onlick="myFuction()"> Try it </button>

    <p id="Begin"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Most of the script was copied from the example I found here but I'm unable to create table based on what I have. All I get is my text and the button mention in body tag.

Any help is appreciated. Again, I just need help with function so that the function creates the table based on user prompted rows and columns.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which HTML element has `'holdTable'` id?

Comment: `onlick="myFuction"` contains two typos. And there is no element with id `taskname`. And my browser can't even display this file, because of the < in the script.